# Centered carousel with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel, owl-carousel

I want to use the bootstrap carousel to build a centered slider with offscreen items. Like this example (the second on the page): http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/center.html

The problem with the example is, that the items are not aligned with the bootstrap grid. Is there any possibility to built it based on the bootsrap carousel and grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. You can give the div ".item" the min-width of the container based on the breakpoint.

For large screens you can do the following:

```
.item {min-width: 1140px}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just place whole carousel to container with `div` with negative side margins like that:

```
<div class="container">
  <div style="margin-left: -45px; margin-right: -45px">
    <div class="loop owl-carousel owl-theme owl-center owl-loaded">
       ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You only need to choose suitable value for that negative margins

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the answer but I don't think this will work on different screen sizes. Or am I wrong?

And I want the slider outside the container in full width. Only the slides should be in the size of the grid/container